# Getting the xpath for this field

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

My code goes into this website, and clicks on each row of a table.

These rows open a window, which contain a field "keywords" at the bottom of the new window, which I am trying to get.

I dont think I have the xpath for this field right, though all I did was right click and "copy xpath".

Expected output is to print the value in the keywords.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://aaaai.planion.com/Web.User/SearchSessions?ACCOUNT=AAAAI&CONF=AM2021&USERPID=PUBLIC&ssoOverride=OFF')
time.sleep(3)
page_source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source,'html.parser')
eachRow=driver.find_elements_by_class_name('clickdiv')

for item in eachRow:
    item.click() #opens the new window per each row
    time.sleep(2)
    faculty = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//td[@valign='MIDDLE']/b") #this works fine
    keywords=item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()') #this does not
    print(keywords.text)
    print(faculty.text)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('XX').click()#closes window
```

```
ERROR message - selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()" is: [object Text]. It should be an element.
```

.....

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Does it not give the expected output? Do you get an error message? What are the errors you get?

Comment: No, it does not give expected output. It gives me an error message

Comment: Can you add your error message with the traceback to your post?

Comment: i have Added this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath `'//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/text()'` is getting the actual text of the element, not the entire element itself. Just remove `text()` and it should work. XPath is notoriously finnicky, so be careful how you use it, and how you are defining your top level root.

I reworked your code very slightly here to give a better option than `time.sleep()`, [explicit waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html?highlight=webdriverwait#explicit-waits). It isn't necessary, but tends to make more reliable code and speeds up processing; it doesn't pause the process unless it has to, and only does so for as long as necessary.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://aaaai.planion.com/Web.User/SearchSessions?ACCOUNT=AAAAI&CONF=AM2021&USERPID=PUBLIC&ssoOverride=OFF')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'clickdiv')))
eachRow = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('clickdiv')

for item in eachRow:
    item.click()  # opens the new window per each row
    faculty = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@valign='MIDDLE']/b")))
    keywords = item.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="W1"]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td')
    print(keywords.text)
    print(faculty.text)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('XX').click()  # closes window
```

Comment: Thanks alot,  and thanks for the explanation